# Win32 module loading from multiple directories

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

I have a program which stores plugins in multiple directories, like so:

```
root/
  core/bin/
    app.exe
    core.dll
    plugin.dll
    support.dll
  a/bin/
    a.dll
    a_support.dll
```

In this example, `a.dll` imports `core.dll`, `support.dll`, and `a_support.dll` (they are in that order in the import table). `a_support.dll` imports `support.dll`. I can change all but the support modules, those are redists of a third-party library.

My code calls `LoadLibraryEx(name, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH)` to load each plugin. For `core.dll` and `plugin.dll`, this works fine.

When I try to load `a.dll`, it fails *saying `a_support.dll` was not found*. No errors about `core.dll` or `support.dll`, perhaps because they're already in memory.

My suspicion is that when `a_support.dll` is loaded, `support.dll` cannot be found, but this seems unusual as `a.dll` appears to import `support.dll` before `a_support.dll`.

Is this layout of modules *even possible* to use? Will the system be able to use the already-loaded support DLLs, or will it go searching for them and fail? Would there be a way to handle this through manifests? Is there a way to make this work, or will I have to relocate all modules into a single directory?

**Edit:** At Adrian McCarthy's suggestion, I ran the loading sequence with Process Monitor tracking, and it seems that when I call `LoadLibrary("root/a/bin/a.dll", ...)`, it starts by searching the root directory, then system directories, then down through the path. For some reason, it never searches `a/bin/`, which it very much should.

I double-checked the paths, and noticed that my calls to load `plugin.dll` where using the wrong path (root, instead of root/core/bin). Either way, `core.dll` was loading correctly. After fixing that, I tried it again and this time `a.dll` does find `a_support.dll` and seems to load. However, that makes absolutely no sense, unless the loader is successfully using `support.dll` from... somewhere. The procmon log doesn't show it even attempting to load `support.dll` again, so I'm not entirely sure at this point if there actually is a problem (besides behavior from the loader that makes no sense).

Comment: I'm not sure I believe your edit. The first place that is searched is the folder with the exe in. I hope you are not really using relative paths like `"root/a/bin/a.dll"`. I hope you are prefixing that with the full path to `root`. Finally I think Adrian has pointed you at the wrong tool. You would be far better off with Dependency Walker running in Profile mode. However, you really need to understand this from the ground up and that is possible just by reading the docs.

Comment: Of course they aren't relative paths, LoadLibraryEx with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` requires absolute paths and I think just errors out on relatives. I am familiar with how loading usually works, this is simply not covered in any docs I've seen. Still, going to do further testing and edit in any applicable details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what's really happening.  You'll see if it's looking in the right place, whether a_support.dll is opened but not loadable because something else is missing, etc.

Comment: Good call, I'd forgotten about that. It gave some interesting results, which I'm editing into the question.

Comment: Dependency Walker in profile mode is the appropriate tool to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly one solution would be to place all DLLs in the same directory, the same directory as the .exe. If you can bring yourself to do that it would be the simplest approach for sure.

If not then you will have a bit more work on your hands. I guess you are expecting that the loader will search in the directory where the DLL lives. Sadly it doesn't. Instead the loader will look first in the executable file's directory, and then the rest of the [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is why `a_support.dll` fails to load, because it is not in the same directory as the executable.

The fact that modules are already in memory is beside the point. The loader goes looking for the file. When it finds the file that it wants it then checks to see if it is already loaded. If so then it simply bumps the reference count to that module. Otherwise it loads it into the process.

You could switch to using `LoadLibrary` for all DLL loads and always being explicit about the path. That's probably inconvenient.

You could use side-by-side assemblies but that doesn't sound very compatible with a plugin architecture.

So I think the main remaining option is [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Call this just before you load the plugin. You only need to add `a/bin` to the search path since the rest of the modules are in the executable directory and so will be found without trouble. Restore this setting to its default by calling `SetDllDirectory` again, passing `NULL`, once the plugin has loaded and resolved all of its imports.

If you have multiple sub-directories then use [`AddDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If, in the future, `b/bin`, `c/bin`, etc are added, then use `AddDllDirectory()` instead of `SetDllDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather confusing application.

Some questions then:

- Which dll's does app.exe implicitly import?
- core.dll is both implicitly loaded by a.dll AND as a plugin via LoadLibraryEx?
- How was the call to LoadLibraryEx on /plugin.dll ever succeeding? If the path was FQ and did not point at an actual dll, LoadLibrary should have failed outright on that dll.

Comment: 1) app.exe doesn't implicitly import any, it uses LoadLibraryEx on core.dll, 2) Yes, 3) I believe it was failing but I wasn't catching it until I went back and double-checked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're giving sample code or real code.  You wrote:

```
LoadLibrary("root/a/bin/a.dll", ...)
```

If that's the real code, there are two problems here.

First, `LoadLibrary` doesn't do what you'd expect with a relative path.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To load a module from a relative path without searching any other
>   path, use GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call
>   LoadLibrary with the nonrelative path. For more information on the DLL
>   search order, see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order.

Basically, you give it a full path and get that file, or you let it search for a name in all the "usual" locations.  If you give it a relative path, it basically ignores that path, grabs the name, and looks in the usual locations.

If you really meant `LoadLibraryEx`, note that when you use `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` you get "undefined behavior" if handed a relative path.  Again quoting [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If this value is used and lpFileName specifies a relative path, the behavior is undefined.

Second, you have forward slashes instead of backslashes.  Neither `LoadLibrary` nor `LoadLibraryEx` likes those.